# UIAlertView (or LMAlertView) with two stacked buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

How can I create an `UIAlertView` with two stacked button? Instead of two buttons side by side? In my project I also use `LMAlertView` ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/lmcd/LMAlertView)) and I thought it would support them, but I can't find a way to obtain that very UIAlertView style.

Currently I create a UIAlertView with this code below:

```
LMAlertView *applicationUpdateAlert = [[LMAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitleFromServer
                                                                 message:alertMessageFromServer
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:NC(@"Aggiorna ora")
                                                       otherButtonTitles:NC(@"Ricordamelo più tardi"), nil];

[applicationUpdateAlert show]
```

I don't know if this can be useful for you to better understand but `LMAlertView` has a property named `buttonsShouldStack` which I thought it would be useful for me but I can't properly use it, this is the code related to `buttonsShouldStack` in LMAlertView.m file ([direct link](https://github.com/lmcd/LMAlertView/blob/f481d4485f25bcb17e13bfb103d99e784dd24bba/LMAlertView/LMAlertView.m#L104)):

```
- (void)setButtonsShouldStack:(BOOL)buttonsShouldStack
{
    _buttonsShouldStack = buttonsShouldStack;

    if (self.numberOfButtons == 2) {
        [self.buttonTableView reloadData];
        [self.otherTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use UIAlertController, UIAlertView is deprecate in iOS 8

Comment: @IxPaka Thanks I knew UIAlertView was deprecated in iOS 8 but the project I'm currently working on still doesn't support iOS 8

Comment: @Aluminum How can you not be supporting iOS 8? You can drop support for lower versions of iOS but you can't drop support for the latest version. So you can drop support for iOS 5 say but you can't drop support for iOS 8 so you must support iOS 8.

Comment: @Popeye It's possible since if you build an application for the iOS 7 deployment target it will run on iOS 8 devices in "backward compatibility" so UIAlertView will still be available. Instead, if you build your application for the iOS 8 deployment target you must use UIAlertController, since you remove iOS 7 compatibility, it's the same for the Swift language.

Comment: @Aluminum I know that that but overall you still have to support iOS8 so why not implement `UIAlertController` with the way you want for iOS 8 and `UIAlertVIew` for iOS 7 and below with the old way?

Comment: @Popeye Because for the moment the project isn't intended for iOS 8, regarding iOS 7 I still can't have a working UIAlertView/LMAlertView with 2 buttons stacked

Comment: @Aluminum even though your main audience is going to be on iOS 8? Well what you are after can't be achieved with `UIAlertView` at all as you aren't allowed to alter the view hierarchy of a `UIAlertView` as it's private. In all honesty it seems you are stuck in the past and not moving with the times.

Comment: @Popeye Since it's not my project I don't bother about that, if it was for me I would even switch completely to Swift and I will stick with UIAlertController, instead of using UIAlertView or a 3rd-party library. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any custom 3rd party libraries that will give you want you want, you may need to modify one to achieve what you are after. I will have a go this evening when home to see if I can change one to get what you want if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by "rewriting" the `LMAlertView` component in order to treat `UIAlertView` buttons as `UITableView`'s cells and by setting the `rowNumber` accordingly, if the alert has to show 1, 2 or more buttons. It's not an easy to show solution so I won't share the code here, also because I don't know if it's Apple's-approval safe.

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give a try with this [library](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView). It has a demo project that cover your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-) I downloaded the library and I will it now, it wasn't updated since 4 years ago but I hope it works :-/